# Regular expression for sequence of decimal numbers

Tags: regex

I have sequence of decimal numbers(upto two places) in following way:

1.2,1.30,1.45,1.6

I tried in following way but it is not accepting multiple commas and multiple dots:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

What changes can be made into it.

Comment: Replace `?` with `*` (0 or more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the questionmark `?` which will make it match zero or 1 time to a quantifier for example `+` that would match one or more times or an asterix `*` to match zero or more times because you have multiple values you want to match.

[`^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/eN16Cz/1)